# Hibernate - Searching - Java heap space

Tags: java, hibernate, heap-memory

I have a java heap space problem with hibernate since I add a modification in mi code.
The program load information from a text file (2GB)

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while (line.compareTo(EOF) != 0) {
    //Load of infoObject, lots of parse information from the text file
    //Read lines of text using: line = input.readLine();

    getSession().save(infoObject);

    counter++;

    if (counter % 100 == 0) {
        getSession().flush();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

This work great, now in case that the infoObject already exists in my db, I need to update the record, I use this:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while (line.compareTo(EOF) != 0) {
    //Load of infoObject

    iObject infoObject_tmp = new iObject();
    infoObject_tmp.setNumAccount(numAccount);
    infoObject_tmp.setCloseDate(new Date("02/24/2011"));
    iObject infoObject_search = (iObject) getSession().load(iObject.class, infoObject_tmp);

    if (infoObject_search !=null){
        getSession().update(infoObject);
    }else{
        getSession().save(infoObject);
    }
    counter++;

    if (counter % 100 == 0) {
        getSession().flush();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

FreeMemory:

- Registry 1: 750283136.
- Registry 10000: 648229608.
- Registry 50000: 411171048.
- Registry 100000: Java Heap Space.

How can i fix the java heap space problem?
I know that the problem is when i check if the iObject exists or not.

Comment: So, what is your question, then?

Comment: How can i fix the java heap space problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a `flush()` followed by a `clear()`.  `flush()` only pushes any pending updates to the database.  `clear()` removes the objects from the session.  you need to be careful with `clear()` though, because any other code which has a reference to an object which was in the session now has a "detached" object.

Comment: This improve the performance a lot, i'm running some test but i think that this solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to tell what exactly is going on without seeing more of your code.  It's also a bit confusing since your `BufferedReader` does not appear to be used.

That said, one possibility, given what it looks like you are doing, is that somewhere you are calling `substring` on some text input and keeping a reference to the `String` object that is returned as a result.  For instance, you might be doing something like this:

```
List<String> allMySubstrings = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
  String mySubstring = line.subString(40, 42);
  // mySubstring still has a reference to the whole character array from line
  allMySubstrings.add(mySubstring);
}
```

You might think then that you will only have references to `allMySubstrings` and not every `line` that was read.  However, because of the way `subString` is implemented, the resulting `String` object will have a reference to the **entire** original character array from `line`, not just the relevant substring.  Garbage collection won't occur as you might expect as a result

If you are doing this, you can get around it by creating a new `String object`:

```
List<String> allMySubstrings = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
  String mySubstring = new String(line.subString(40, 42));
  allMySubstrings.add(mySubstring);
}
```

Note that this might be happening even if you do not **explicitly** call `subString` as common methods like `split` might be responsbile.

Comment: The problem is not reading the file, I take out the code that check if the account exists, and the memory performance is great.Any way i will check the strings, thank you!

Comment: @JMira Does the code checking if the account exists call `split` or `subString` on `line` and hold on to the results in some collection by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You declare `BufferedReader input`, but you never seem to use it. Could it be that the `line` Object that you refer to in the `while` loop is accessing the underlying `File` in a non-buffered way?

Comment: Yes, I don't put the whole code because is really big, but I use:   line = input.readLine(); To access the text file.

Comment: Does the file contain line terminating characters (`\n` or `\r`)?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not reading the file, I take out the code that check if the account exists, and the memory performance is great.